# Single hibernate sessions in a single thread causing deadlock

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm attempting to put in a temporary workaround for a race condition in a java server using hibernate. The code initially looks like this:

```
s = sessionFactory.openSession();
Object o1 = dao.getMostRecentVersionOfObject(key, s);
if (o1.performSomeTimeConsumingTask() == Looks.Ok) {
    Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();
    dao.update(o1, s);
    t.commit();
}
```

The original problem is that if 2 different threads get to the same block of code at roughly the same time, they will both try and get the same version of the object, so the second one will always fail. Since there are multiple, load balanced servers, the real solution to this problem is to use a distributed locking system to make sure that versions are kept in sync and that transactions don't tread on each others toes.  However, since users are already finding this to be a problem and a long term solution to this problem will take time to develop, I made the executive decision to add a temporary hack by checking to see if the object has been updated just before the transaction starts. I created a second session to perform this version check. If there's been an update I use the second session to populate the object's fields then save it. So the new code looks a little like this:

```
Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();
Session transactionSession = s;
Object o1 = dao.getMostRecentVersionOfObject(key, s);
int version = o1.getVersion();
if (o1.performSomeTimeConsumingTask() == Looks.Ok) {
    Session newerSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Object newerObject = dao.getMostRecentVersionOfObject(key, newerSession);
    if (newerObject.getVersion() > version) {
        // update fields...
        transactionSession = newSession;
    }
}
Transaction t = transactionSession.beginTransaction();
dao.update(o1, transactionSession);
t.commit();
```

This code works in several environments, but fails in the most important one due to a reported deadlock. This happens when there isn't even a second concurrent request to the method -- the second session gets created, checks the version and then gets ignored while the first session performs the commit transaction. I suspect that this issue is either environmental (but I don't see why this would be the case), or that hibernate doesn't like the use of the second session but this is just an educated guess. I'm particularly confused as to why hibernate would report this as a deadlock since there's only a single transaction.

Any ideas on this are much appreciated!

Comment: When a deadlock is reported, what lines are the different threads at? An alternative solution here would be to just attempt to repeat the transaction/work if you get StaleObjectException

Answer (score 0):

> The original problem is that if 2 different threads get to the same block of code at roughly the same time, they will both try and get the same version of the object, so the second one will always fail.

Your second solution still have the same problem. You are doing this,

1. Get the latest object
2. Update fields if version is not same
3. Commit updated object

When you are doing step 2, other thread would have updated the object.

If you want to prevent this from happening, synchronize the method(least preferred) or do the following,

```
Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();
Object o1 =s.get('o1s class',key,new LockOptions(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE));
//Do whatever you want with o1
//Update o1
//commit
```

The idea is to get object by obtaining lock for update from db.See [doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#get%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable,%20org.hibernate.LockOptions%29). You should be aware of pros and cons of using pessimistic locking over optimistic locking.